# Apply html_strip and lowercase filter on keyword analyzed field

Tags: elasticsearch

I tried to apply html_strip and lowercase filter on a keyword analyzed field. While searching i noticed that the search results are not as expected.

This is the index that we tried to create

```
PUT /test_index
{
  "settings": {
  "number_of_shards": 5,
  "number_of_replicas": 0,
  "analysis": {
    "analyzer": {
      "ExportPrimaryAnalyzer": {
        "type": "custom",
        "tokenizer": "whitespace",
        "filter": "lowercase",
        "char_filter": "html_strip"
      },
      "ExportRawAnalyzer": {
        "type": "custom",
        "buffer_size": "1000",
        "tokenizer": "keyword",
        "filter": "lowercase",
        "char_filter": "html_strip"
      }
    }
  }
}, 
  "mappings": {
    "test_type": {
      "properties": {
        "city": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer" : "ExportPrimaryAnalyzer"
        },
        "city_raw":{
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer" : "ExportRawAnalyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And following is the data example :

```
PUT test_index/test_type/4
{
  "city": "<p>I am from Pune</p>",
  "city_raw": "<p>I am from Pune</p>"
}
```

When we try to do wildcard on it, we are not getting results. Following is the query we tried to fire.

```
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "city_raw": "i am*"
    }
  }
}
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

`html_strip_filter` would replace html block elements with `new-lines`. 
 Hence if you use a `keyword-tokenizer` you would need an additional filter to replace the `new-lines` with empty string.

Example :

```
PUT test
{
   "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 5,
      "number_of_replicas": 0,
      "analysis": {
         "char_filter": {
            "remove_new_line": {
               "type": "mapping",
               "mappings": [
                  "\\n =>"
               ]
            }
         },
         "analyzer": {
            "ExportPrimaryAnalyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "whitespace",
               "filter": [
                  "lowercase"
               ],
               "char_filter": [
                  "html_strip"
               ]
            },
            "ExportRawAnalyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "buffer_size": "1000",
               "tokenizer": "keyword",
               "filter": [
                  "lowercase"
               ],
               "char_filter": [
                  "html_strip",
                  "remove_new_line"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings": {
      "test_type": {
         "properties": {
            "city": {
               "type": "string",
               "analyzer": "ExportPrimaryAnalyzer"
            },
            "city_raw": {
               "type": "string",
               "analyzer": "ExportRawAnalyzer"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}

PUT test/test_type/4
{
  "city": "<p>I am from Bangalore I like Pune too</p>",
  "city_raw": "<p>I am from Bangalore I like Pune too</p>"
}

post test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "city_raw": "i am *"
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
"hits": [
     {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "test_type",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
           "city": "<p>I am from Bangalore I like Pune too</p>",
           "city_raw": "<p>I am from Bangalore I like Pune too</p>"
        }
     }
  ]
```